# Python while True positioning confusion

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic

I have made a rock paper scissors program as I am just beginning but I have discovered that the 2 positions I tried putting a while True: command have completely opposite effects. I can't understand the logic/reasoning behind it and was hoping someone would be able to explain it in simple terms.

the first copy of the code is the one that functions properly with the while True: on the 3rd line.

the second version of the code is what I had done first with the while True: on the 6th line.

the second version results in the result of the game being printed endlessly so E.G. "You win" a million times whereas when the while True: is on the 3rd line it runs as intended with the win/lose or tie message only printing once.

Can someone explain why that is just so I understand for future reference.

```
import random
moves = "rock", "paper", "scissors"
while True:
    computer = moves[random.randint(0,2)]
    player = input("Choose rock, paper or scissors... Or 'end' to end the game: ")

    if player == "end":
        print("Game over!")
        break
    elif player == "rock" and computer == "scissors" or player == "scissors" and computer == "paper" or player == "paper" and computer == "rock":
        print("You win", player, "beats", computer)
    elif player == computer:
        print("Tie!")
    else: 
        print("You lose!", computer, "beats", player)
```

```
import random
moves = "rock", "paper", "scissors"

computer = moves[random.randint(0,2)]
player = input("Choose rock, paper or scissors... Or 'end' to end the game: ")
while True:
    if player == "end":
        print("Game over!")
        break
    elif player == "rock" and computer == "scissors" or player == "scissors" and computer == "paper" or player == "paper" and computer == "rock":
        print("You win", player, "beats", computer)
    elif player == computer:
        print("Tie!")
    else: 
        print("You lose!", computer, "beats", player)
```

Comment: What? Why did you think moving where the loop starts _wouldn't_ change the behaviour? It fundamentally changes what's in and what's out of the loop.

Comment: In the second program you don't change the value of player, and al to elif/else cases don't break so you continuality keep in that state

Comment: The `input` function allows the user to input something in the CLI, the program is interrupted until an input is made. Since you moved it out of the loop, the user is never prompted again.

Comment: Minor note: `computer = moves[random.randint(0,2)]` involves hardcoding magic numbers (the known length of `moves`) into the code, and it's not obvious that it is in fact an exhaustive selection unless the person maintaining the code rechecks the definition of `moves`. Replace it with `computer = random.choice(moves)`, which has none of these problems (it says exactly what you intend to do without repeating information in obscure ways, and in fact uses a somewhat more efficient index generation method; `randint` is three layers of wrapping from the underlying index generation).